# How to match the following string in Tcl?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string like:

```
"[01][03].name.firstname     = 1"
```

I try to using the following to match it:
"`\[01\]\[03\].name\.firstname\s*=\s*1"`  but it does not work, how to match the string?

Comment: Not that it would solve the problem, but you might want to escape the first period, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful about how you quote the pattern:

```
set s {[01][03].name.firstname     = 1}
regexp {\[01\]\[03\].name\.firstname\s*=\s*1} $s      ;# true
regexp "\[01\]\[03\].name\.firstname\s*=\s*1" $s      ;# false
```

Note that with double quotes, if you don't backslash-escape the backslashes, this happens:

```
% puts "\[01\]\[03\].name\.firstname\s*=\s*1" 
[01][03].name.firstnames*=s*1
```

So your pattern isn't what you think it is.

If you somehow *need* to use double quotes, you need lots of backslashes

```
regexp "\\\[01]\\\[03]\\.name\\.firstname\\s*=\\s*1" $s
```

Comment: +1: He might also want a range there like `[0-3]`; hard to say for sure without knowing more examples to match.

Comment: hello, the string actually is "[01][03].name.firstname     = 1", 1 is a tapo, it should be [01], so the question is how to match this string? do I need to escape the first period?

Comment: ok, so in the double quotes version, which blackslash should be escaped? should it like "\[01\\]\[03\\].name\.firstname\s*=\s*1"?

Comment: @user2131316 In a [Tcl double quoted word](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8), 4 characters have special meaning: `"` terminates the word, `[` does command substitution, `$` does variable substitution and `\\` does backslash substitution. Backslash-escape them.

Comment: but here why we need to escape three times \\\[01]? and the ] does not need to escape?

Comment: In the regex, you need a backslash character and an open bracket, so you have an escaped backslash (\\\) and an escaped bracket (\\[) -- three backslashes. Since the open bracket is escaped, the close bracket has no special meaning.